# Cannot connect to server without using connection.getResponseCode()?

Tags: android, django, http, httpurlconnection

Why i cannot connect to server(Django Server) without using connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK from android client Application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: you can. Why you think that you can't?